# Validating gltf/glb files on nodejs using babylonjs

Tags: node.js, validation, gltf, babylonjs, 3d-model

I'm trying to validate a gltf/glb for some errors in the model on server side using babylon.js. I'm using this [package](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js) .I found [this](https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/classes/babylon.gltfvalidation) documentation on babylonjs website about gltf validation but couldn't find equivalent function/classes on the npm package that i am using right now.

Any help if someone has experience on the babylonJs package.

Comment: I think it should work something like that: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#WGZLGJ#2534 but for some reason I did not quite get there. Maybe it helps you a bit...

Comment: @frankenapps ah thanks for the reply but it seems i needed to install 'babylonjs-loaders' as well in order to use the validation functions.

Comment: You can also call the [glTF-Validator](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Validator) directly, or bring it in [via NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltf-validator).